# Linux bridge (brctl) dosnt forward IP packet when router is one of the bridge endpoints

Tags: networking, tcp, bridge, ip-forwarding, bridge-router

I have setup a brctl bridge on Ubuntu with the following deployment:

```
Cisco router -> Linux bridge -> client computer
```

The bridge forward the following packets types: `ARP,STP`, but doesn't forward IP.(I see that it get IP packets in eth0 but dosnt forward to eth1)

Trying `brctl br0 stp off` (and `on`) doesn't help.

Trying to activate both ethernet cards with promisc mode doesn't help either.

Set edge to 0 (and set max edge to 0) doesn't help either.

brctl setfd bridgename time , dosnt help.

Ebtables dosnt install on the bridge computer, so this is not problem of ebtables filtering.

When I replace the router with a simple computer that simulates simple TCP request the bridge forwards the IP packets, so I suspect `STP`.

The bridge was set like this:

```
iptables -X
iptables -F
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0 up
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1
ifconfig br0 up
```

Comment: Try giving your ethernet devices a real ip not 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

Bridge forwards ethernet packets, not just IP:

forwarding delay:
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#Forwarding_delay

ethernet filtering:
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#No_traffic_gets_trough_.28except_ARP_and_STP.29

Comment: ebtables dosnt installed and setfd dosnt help :(

Comment: Are you using vlans? Which distro?
"bridge-nf-call-iptables - pass (1) or don't pass (0) bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables' chains."

Comment: Old comment, both links are dead.